# Whoosh_search unexpected keyword 'like'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, whoosh

I'm using flask_whooshalchemy and trying to do partial matches on texts. 
In the [docs for flask_whooshalchemy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-WhooshAlchemyPlus/0.7.5) it mentions using a 'like' parameter. So I have this query:

```
result = Property.query.whoosh_search(search_str, like=True).filter(
            min_price <= Property.asking_price)
```

But this throws an unexpected keyword argument. Clearly they're using it in the docs and curious what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: What version are you using? Seems that support for SQL LIKE was added in 0.7.4.

Comment: I noticed I was using flask_whooshalchemy but the docs I linked are for flask_whooshalchemyplus. Now I'm using that library and haven't changed the code but getting a bunch of application out of context errors. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong library - should have been using Flask_whooshalchemyplus.